# How to find an amount of unique words in an array(python) , given limitation of 5 mb memory and 5 seconds time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Good day to anyone, who reached my question. I was trying to solve the problem of finding an amount of unique words, that will be typed in as an input, and the first input will be an amount of words going to be typed. Like this:

5
    
track
    
lost

scale

lost

table

 Right answer should be: 4

I've tried to solve the question in Python, like this:

```
a=set()
x = int(input())
a.add(x)
for i in range(x):
    y = input()
    a.add(y)
print(len(a)-1)
```

It appears to work just fine, only not being efficient in terms of memory(it exceeds memory limitations, on high inputs). Is there any more efficient way of solving this problem?

Comment: yes, why not ? It is a set, so only unique words are going to be stored. At the end I am counting the length of the set, and substracting one , because the first input(number of words in total) shouldn't be counted.

Comment: Why do you add number of words read from user also to `a`? If you avoid this, `len(a) -1` can be shortened to `len(a)`.

Comment: I was trying to save space by not creating new set for that.

Comment: `x` need not be saved to any `set`.

Comment: I get it now. I deleted it from set, but the problem is still the same - it exceeds memory limitation.

Comment: How many input words make it exceed the 5 MB limitation?

Comment: It is said that input words may not be more than 500 000.

Comment: @DerteTrdelnik which you already did by referencing this wiki article =)

Comment: Agree with @DerteTrdelnik - a trie will save a significant amount of memory. This is because, unlike a `set`, a trie can store e.g. "underwater" and "underwear" without needing to store two copies of "underw".

Comment: sorry deleted my comment suggesting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie, as I saw another comment about keeping half a million words - I am not sure if the asker is using the right tool for some challange .. as python is not the best when it comes to optimizing for time and space on challanges

Comment: It should be possible in some way, because these limitations were given in the statement of the problem for Python. For C++ they were much stricter.

Comment: @Farid Hasanov so probably try the Tries...

Comment: If you have 5mb limit for 500K words, that comes out to be 10 bytes per word if all words are unique and you have to store them. The minumum sized object in python (the `object()`) itself is 16 bytes. So it seems a challenge. Nonetheless if you store the `hash` of the words instead of the words themselves you can cut down a lot, it becomes the size of an `int`. In the same sessions any logic to test uniqueness (e.g. using `set`) of `x` should transfer to `hash(x)` as well.

Comment: How do I go if I want to hash my inputs?

Answer (score 2):

Cheapo memory saving available because you're on Python 3.6+: Use a `dict`, not a `set`. Despite needing to store a value for each element, `dict`s often used a little less memory even in older versions of Python (they're optimized for different things; `set` tends to overallocate buckets to reduce the risk of bucket collisions, but that costs more memory); in 3.6+ they moved to a more compact `dict` design that saves even more so long as the unique data isn't huge (`set`s can start to win again for some sizes when the number of unique items exceeds `2**15`/32768, as the compactness gains drop off dramatically at that point).

So to change it, just do:

```
a = {}
x = int(input())
for _ in range(x):
    a[input()] = None
print(len(a))
```

Also, for speed, if you don't need to use `input`, you should probably avoid it and just read from `sys.stdin` directly; `input` does a lot of unnecessary flushing of outputs and other work that you don't really need here. So it would likely be even faster to do:

```
import itertools, sys

x = int(input())
a = dict.fromkeys(itertools.islice(sys.stdin.buffer, x))
print(len(a))
```

which just directly pulls the lines without modification and shoves them directly into the `dict` at the C level for extra speed. Change `sys.stdin` to `sys.stdin.buffer` to avoid decoding the strings at all, and wrap in `map(str.rstrip, ...)` or `map(bytes.rstrip, ...)` for `sys.stdin.buffer` to remove newlines (if the last line might not end in a newline, this is necessary for correctness, and I suppose it saves a trivial amount of memory).

If the inputs might be huge (higher five figure unique inputs), then `dict` likely won't help, so just stick with `set`, but you can still use the `sys.stdin` optimizations, leading to a final form like:

```
x = int(input())
a = set(itertools.islice(map(bytes.rstrip, sys.stdin.buffer), x))
print(len(a))
```

Comment: BTW, just to quantify the gain from moving to `bytes`: For pure ASCII text on 64 bit CPython, each `str` requires 16 additional bytes of memory (if the empty `str` weren't a singleton, it would cost 49 bytes, vs. 33 for the equivalent `bytes` object, each extra character adds one more byte to each). If the input is `utf-8` encoded text with non-ASCII characters though, the cost can increase significantly (the base overhead goes up, and for non-latin-1 characters, the cost per character doubles or quadruples as well).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the expected nature of the data:

- for dictionary words, especially similar ones, use a trie
- for long texts, use lossless compression

Example for **zlib** compression:

```
import zlib

a = set()
x = int(input())
for _ in range(x):
    a.add(zlib.compress(input().encode()))
    #a.add(input())

print("unique: ", len(a))

print("memory: ", sum(len(b) for b in a))
```

Uncompressed:

```
> echo -e "3\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\nbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" | python3 c.py
unique:  2
memory:  32
```

Compressed:

```
> echo -e "3\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\nbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" | python3 c.py
unique:  2
memory:  22
```

Comment: The odds of *per word* `zlib` compression helping with actual words you're likely to be passed is basically zero. You've constructed fake words that happen to compress extremely well, but while English words follow a few known patterns, the odds of those patterns recurring *in a given word* enough for `zlib` to benefit you is basically zero. A trie would at least provide some statefulness across words, and might save memory; provide an example of that, not `zlib`, which is basically guaranteed to be useless.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Agreed, for regular english words I propose a trie too, but for random words (e.g. some generated IDs) or general texts (thousands of characters) a compression may give better memory savings. The example shows that at least one case where zlib is better than trie exists. Also there may be a compression library more suitable for short character strings than zlib.

Answer (score -1):

It came 2 solutions to my head. First one is use a JSON structure. JSON structure uses a unique key, then, you can create this structure and then check how many keys do you have.

The code will look something like this

For both examples i will assume you have an array with all the words, this array will be `words_array`

```py
unique_words = {}
for word in words_array:
  unique_words[word.lower().strip()] = 1 
  # this  one could be any value
  # i just need to create the key value

print len(unique_words)
```

I used `lower` and `strip` to be sure this word is unique no matter the uppercase or spaces in the word.

The other method is to check in an array if word already exists, this method works but it is less efficient

```py
unique_words = []
for word in words_array:
  w = word.lower().strip()
  if not w in unique_words:
    unique_words.append(w)

print len(unique_words)
```

I thing if you are looking for memory efficiency I will suggest other alternative like using C